# How is the internal energy changed if an atom is charged?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics

I read this statement from an exam:

*A neutral carbon atom gains 4 electrons, this atom has a higher internal energy after the addition than before.*

I am not sure whether it is correct, in particular, I am unclear on how the internal energy of the atom is defined. Can someone help me. Many thanks.

Comment: Seeing as at least 3 of those electrons depart immediately, that seems a very odd question from a physics perspective.